# jQuery on click not working with class name

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am still getting use to jQuery and coding in general, I would like to know why this on click jQuery function is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".galleryImg").click(function(){
    alert("hey");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="galImgArea">
  <img class="galleryImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on your browser's development console?

Comment: Indeed.  Use your browser's developer console - the errors that are output there will tell you pretty clearly what's going on.

Comment: `**strong text**` ` isn't valid statement in js if you used it in source code

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Its not displaying any errors the function just does nothing, when i did $('*').click.... That worked but seems to not work with any specific class click

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the line `**strong text**`.
You also have to added the link for `JQuery` library i.e line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. This is very basic requirement for working with any `JavaScript` library.
Following is corrected-complete code, which is working:

```html
<div class="galImgArea">
  <img class="galleryImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".galleryImg").click(function(){
        alert("hey");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have added the library other elemenrs work with jquery only this element doesnt seem to work

Comment: @mattdober Did you removed the content `**strong text**`? If it refers some other code then, Could you provide your complete code here? Because the code you provided here is working as you can see in my posted-answer.

Comment: the strong text was nothing  I added it on stack overflow by mistake

Comment: @mattdober Are you able to successfully run the code available in my answer at your end? You can do so by clicking on `Run code snippet` button below the code snippet.

Comment: @mattdober After edit by _Shiladitya_ in your question, it is working fine in my Chrome 70.0 browser on Windows 10. Which browser and Operating System are you using?